# Dialogflow cuts off number input at 3-4 digits

Tags: regex, dialogflow-es, numeric, voice-recognition

I'm currently making a voice assistent and I'm running into the following issue:

The voice detection of Google Dialogflow severely butchers my numeric inputs spoken into the assistent.
Like when I clearly pronounce "One nine, eight, seven, two, three" it will turn it into 987 or 1987. It just seems to cut off listening and continues straight away when it thinks it has a full entity.

I have made a custom composite entity that is built up out of three different recognition patterns.

- **@sys.number-integer:number-integer**
- NumberRegex **^([1-9]{1}([0-9]){1,4}[0-9]{1})$**
- NumberCardinals **@sys.cardinal:cardinal** (repeating 3-6 times as composite entity)

Basically what I want to detect is a numeric input consisting of 3 numbers minimum and 6 maximum.
Typing works great, it detects all combinations flawlessly whether it's cardinals or numbers...

But speech is just a huge problem, and it cuts off before the user has finished speaking.

Anyone got any suggestions on how to overcome this? And force DialogFlow to listen to the max amount of numbers?

Comment: I don't think it will fix the problem, but the pattern could be shortened to `^[1-9][0-9]{2,5}$`

Comment: Definitely didn't resolve the issue and yes that's a cleaner way of writing the same regex as up above, I had this because I also wanted to allow for spaces between the numbers.

Comment: Your original pattern would not match a space between numbers. If you want to match spaces between numbers (not before the first and not after the last number) you might use `^[1-9](?: *[0-9]){2,5}$` If you want to match whitespaces, you can replace the space and asterix with `\s*`

Comment: I've ran into this when working with Google Assistant. This isnt so much an issue with Dialogflow. As you mentioned, when entering text it works fine. Dialogflow only processes what it gets from the device that records the users speech. So in this case it is an issue with the speech recognition on whatever device you are using and you cant really change anything about the recognition itself. **Have you tried guiding your user to not say "One Two" or "Three Four", but instead use "Twelve" and "Fourty three"? The recognition was much better at that than single digit input.**